# DataStudio: Wrong numbers after data blending

Tags: looker-studio

I have 2 tables from the same data source, same columns, one of them is filtered. For calculating total count `COUNT_DISTINCT(another_field)` metric is used. The percentages are calculated as `COUNT_DISTINCT(another_field)` and used the `Percent of total` comparison function. Title is the dimension.

| Title | Total count | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| title1 | 1,734 | 47.36% |

| Title | Total count(filtered) | Percentage(filtered) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| title1 | 1,639 | 45.69% |

Which are correct numbers. Now after blending these 2 tables joined by Title I get.

| Title | Total count | Percentage | Total count(filtered) | Percentage(filtered) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| title1 | 1,734 | 6.18% | 1,639 | 9.97% |

Now what happened to the percentages? Why did they change? And how to accomplish this joined table with the same numbers as in the separated ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of my problem is that when I blend the data it's already aggregated so the percentages lose the sense of the base data. The correct workaround was to just create 2 charts with no aggregated dimensions or any metrics (one filtered, the other one - not), then manage the blended data to add any fields that are going to be used as a dimension, and only then aggregate the data on the blended chart.